# How do I tell CMake to output the package search paths?

Tags: windows, cmake

I'm compiling [libdwarf](https://github.com/tomhughes/libdwarf) on Windows. In its root `CMakeLists.txt`, it attempts to find [LibElf](https://github.com/WolfgangSt/libelf) via:

```
find_package(LibElf REQUIRED)
```

LibElf doesn't use CMAKE and I haven't configured it to register itself in any way, so of course the `find_package` fails. I'd like CMake to print out all the paths under which it is searching for LibElf at runtime. How do I tell CMake to output this? I've tried `--trace` but that just show me the execution flow through my `CMakeLists.txt` files--not the locations where CMake itself is presently looking for packages.

I know the [documentation for find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) describes where CMake searches, but I can modify that behavior with all sorts of variables, environment variables, and registry settings. I'd like to see where exactly CMake is looking given all my modifications to those items I just mentioned.

I should note that `libdwarf` includes a `cmake/FindLibElf.cmake` module. Perhaps what I'm asking for isn't possible if `FindLibElf.cmake` is free to do whatever it pleases?

Answer (score 17):

Since version 3.17 CMake provides the option `--debug-find`, which results in output of a ton of **debug information** about search process of `find_package` and other `find_*` commands:

```
cmake --debug-find <...>
```

The similar effect could be achieved by setting the variable [CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE.html).

One may set the variable either in the command line:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE=1 <...>
```

or in the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_DEBUG_MODE 1)
```

Comment: I tried this on cmake 3.13.3 on Windows and saw no noticeable effect. I tried specifying on the command line and in my root CMakeLists.txt. I tried with and without --trace and --debug-output at the same time. Does this still work for recent versions of CMake?

Comment: Hm, in my CMake 3.11 on Linux this doesn't work too... But they use the variable in their tests. May be, someone else could sched light on this.

Comment: It seems this was added only "recently" and is targeted for CMake 3.17: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/3935

Comment: Updated the answer with specific CMake version. Also noted `--debug-find` option.